# Size of ArrayList in Java after caching lines in a text file

Tags: java, arraylist

Size of the text file is 15 mb. I'm caching the lines of the text into an `ArrayList<String>`.

It's straightforward caching, no transformations,etc...

I got the size of the ArrayList using `ObjectSizeCalculator.getObjectSize()` and it gave me 51mb

How does the 15 mb data in file gets inflated into 51 mb, assuming I'm correct in using ObjectSizeCalculator.getObjectSize() for calculation?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader newBufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(INPUT_PATH))) {
        newBufferedReader.lines().forEach(x -> {
            stringList.add(x);
        });
    }

    System.out.println("Size: " + ObjectSizeCalculator.getObjectSize(stringList)/1000000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the text file itself may be encoded as a bunch of, say, Unicode codepoints, your ArrayList. However, your ArrayList contains tons of String objects. While a String is basically a wrapper around a `char[]`, it stil takes up more space than a simple array. Because of how many lines are in your text file (I assume there's probably hundreds), this difference multiplies. There's also a little more added because the ArrayList itself is an object, but that's probably negligible compared to what the Strings add.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList has internal array to store elements and when you add element to array list when that internal array is full it will be resized to become 50% larger. And it will consume memory for that.